# How to show that $\sup(\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)) = b$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $a<b$ be two real numbers. Show that $\sup(\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)) = b$ and $\inf(\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)) = a$.

This intuitively makes sense. Since a sequence of rationals will infinitely approach $a$ and $b$, it makes sense that the question is true. How do I prove it rigorously?

Comment: You need to prove that doesnt exist $c<b$ such that $c\ge x,\forall x\in \Bbb Q\cap (a,b)$

Comment: Use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The $\mathbb Q \cap$ stuff is a bit of a red herring.  The proof/argument is the same for $(a,b) \subset \mathbb R$ and restricting to the rationals doesn't affect either the sup or the argument that b is the sup.  Use the literal definition of sup.  b > t $\in (a,b)$ so b is an upper bound.  If t < b$ then there exist a rational number q s.t. t < q < b by the density of the rationals... oh, I guess it *wasn't* such a red herring after all... so $q \in$ the set so t is not an upperbound.  So b is the least upper bound.  By definition.

Comment: Have you ever tried to write down by *definition* what $\sup(\mathbb{Q}\cap(a,b))=b$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$.
It should be clear that $a,b$ are lower & upper bounds respectively.

There are sequences $a_n \downarrow a, b_n \uparrow b$ with $a_n,b_n \in A$,
hence $a \le \inf A \le a_n$ and $b \ge \sup A \ge b_n$ for all $n$, hence we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\Bbb{Q}\cap (a,b)$. Of course, $b\geq x$ for all $x\in A$. Suppose that the supremum of $A$ is $m<b$. By density, there exists $r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap(m,b)$. Hence, $r\in A$ and $r>m$, which contradicts the maximality of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition of supremum. We need to show that
(1) $b$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$, and
(2) $\forall b'<b$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$.

We only need to prove (2). Without loss of generality, we can suppose $b'>a$.
Since $b'<b$ and $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, i.e. we can find $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $q\in (b',b)$. Thus, $q\in\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$ and larger than $b'$.
Hence, $b'$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$.